# Can you print variables based on a string in a different dataframe?

Tags: r, excel, if-statement

I am writing code in R that basically will read an Excel (`data`) and print a string from (data.2) based on a word in a particular cell and column.

In short, R reads the Excel file using `readxl` I used `regmatches` and `regexpr` to find a word and print out the whole string. E.g. `regmatches(data$Name, regexpr(.*HEALTH.*, data$Name))`. It worked and shows the whole name based on the word 'health'.

Next, I would like the code to print 2 new variables (main field and sub) from `data.2` in a new column. E.g. `data.2 %>% select(main.field, sub)%>% filter(grepl("health care", sub))`

I have used a `fuzzyjoin` command and `ifelse` statements but they didn't work. I have also created a function that didn't work. Example of the function is below

```
function (x) {
  ifelse(regmatches(
    data$Name, regexpr(".*health.*", data$Name)), 
    gsub("NA", 
         data.2 %>% 
           select(main field, sub) %>% 
           filter(grepl("health care", sub)), 
         data[3], 
         x)
}
```

Is there a way for R to print the main field and sub columns based on a word in a string from a different data frame (`data`)?

Example dataset below

```
data<- data.frame(Name = c("health community group", "trade etf 22",  "hello mag", "bank", "shares fund"),
              Country = c("uk","uk", "au", "za", "us"),
              Main.field = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
              sub = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"))

data.2<- data.frame(Main.field = c("corp", "corp", "mutual fund", "corp", "corp", "gov"),sub = c("health care", "bank", "mutual fund", "publishing", "mining", "gov"))
```

Regex - finding and printing

```
regmatches(data$Name,regexpr(".*health.*",data$Name))

data.2 %>% select(Main.field, sub)%>% filter(grepl("health care", sub)))
```

Trialling a function

```
foo <- function (x){
  ifelse(
    regmatches(data$Name, regexpr(".*health.*", data$Name)),
    gsub(
      "NA",
      data.2 %>% 
        select(Main.field, sub) %>%
        filter(grepl("health care", sub)),
      data[3], 
      x
    ))
}

The code for the output 

read 'etf' - `regmatches(data$FamilyName, regexpr(".*etf.*", data$FamilyName)`
print - `data.2 %>% select(Main.field, sub) %>%filter(grepl("mutual", sub))`

read 'mag' - `regmatches(data$FamilyName, regexpr(".*mag.*", data$FamilyName)`
print - `data.2 %>% select(Main.field, sub) %>%filter(grepl("publishing", sub))`

read 'bank' - regmatches(data$FamilyName, regexpr(".*bank.*", data$FamilyName)
print - data.2 %>% select(Main.field, sub) %>%filter(grepl("bank", sub))

So the new dataframe should look like this -

   dput(output<- data.frame(Name = c("health community group", "trade etf 22",  "hello mag", "bank", "shares fund"),
                    Country = c("uk","uk", "au", "za", "us"),
                    Main.field = c("corp", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                    sub = c("health provider", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")))

In short, I would like R to assign strings to the `Main.field` and `sub` columns (from `data.2`) based on words in the `Name` column from the `data` dataframe

`print(output)`
                    Name Country Main.field             sub
1 health community group      uk       corp health provider
2           trade etf 22      uk         NA              NA
3              hello mag      au         NA              NA
4                   bank      za         NA              NA
5            shares fund      us         NA              NA
```

Comment: Hi Dav, welcome to SO. Could you add some example data with `dput` to make this reproducible? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dav, maybe you can format your code? I edited your post but the edit queue is full; I think you can edit the post though. Wrap in-line code with a single backtic (`) and code blocs with triple backtics (```).

Comment: @MichealRoswell Thank you for editing the code! I have tried to use the triple backtics for the bloc of code but it doesn't seem to be working. I've also added the `dput` so hopefully this helps

Comment: I've mostly cleaned up the formatting and syntax. I don't understand what you're going for. Could you show, for this sample input, what is the desired output? I also named your trial function so it could be called. It's strange to have `function(x)` not use `x`---maybe you want a function with no arguments `function()` or perhaps it would be better to have `data` and `data.2` as arguments?

Comment: And do you **only** need this to work on "health" or are there key words/patterns for the other Main.fields? Please do show the complete output you're hoping for the sample data if you want this to work on more than just "health". I'm worried that the result you want could be one join with a little pattern matching, but you're thinking about it one pattern at a time which will be more complicated.

Comment: @GregorThomas It should work for all the names but I only showed "health" as an experience. I've added an output code so you can see how it should print

Comment: For your example, could you show the full output, not just for "health"? Like, what words/patterns are you looking for. As I said, I think it will be easier to do them all at once than one at a time, but that we need to know what to look for to know how to generalize it.

Comment: @GregorThomas  That's fine, I'll include the full output in the question. Though, in brief, all I need the code to do is read a specific word and print a string based on the word.